# C Socket server is not catching incoming connections

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

as in the title, i have a C TCP socket application with a server and a client on Linux. The server is listening for connection on the port 28000 at localhost address 127.9.0.1. Sometimes, happens that the client "prints a connect statement" so the connect() has been done. This makes me think that the server accepted the connection request. However, the client "connects" and at the first data recv from the server it "freezes". But in reality the server is not ready to send data, so the client stays on that state. This happens randomly, and frequently after recompiling. I really don't know where the problem could be, as this happens only to my pc (tryied native Linux, WSL and VM), i tryied executing on another PC and happens VERY fewer times.

I want to clarify that this doesn't happens everytime, i made whole system to run. The binding of the address is fine, the connect() on client and accept() on server are OK. For example, shutting the pc and booting up, made connection work.

The code is quite long (probably has some errors) and has some very bad code practice, please don't blame me:

**server.c**

```
        #include "Client_List.h"

        #define BACKLOG 10

        typedef struct _t_args_comm
        {
            user* a;
            user* b;
        }COMMUNICATION;


        bool debug = true;
        int socket_ds; 
        clientNode *Clientlist;

        void* ConnectionHandler(void*);
        void getClientList(clientNode*, char**, int);
        void desc_init(clientNode*, struct pollfd*);
        void* Lobby();
        void SIGINT_handler(int);
        void ErrorServer(const char*, bool);


        int main(int argc, char** argv)
        {
            if(argc == 2)
            {
                if(strcmp(argv[1], "true") == 0)
                    debug = true;
                else
                {
                    printf("Wrong parameter, Usage: ./server [true], exiting from the program\n");
                    exit(-1);
                }
            }

            int res, connect_index, client_sock_ds;
            socklen_t clientLength;
            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
            struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
            char check[32];
            pthread_t lobby_tid;
            struct sigaction sig;
            sigset_t set;

            sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
            sig.sa_mask = set;
            sig.sa_handler = SIGINT_handler;

            // Opening a TCP socket using IP_V4
            if((socket_ds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
                ErrorServer("socket open", true);

            printf("[+] Server socket is created!\n");

            // Setting up the sockaddr_in struct that will store server's address's informations
            memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);    // to byte order conversion; 

            // Binding ip address to the socket
            if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(serv_addr.sin_addr)) <= 0)
                ErrorServer("inet_pton()", true);

            // Binding the server address to the socket
            if(bind(socket_ds, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1)
                ErrorServer("bind", true);

            // Setting up backlog
            if(listen(socket_ds, BACKLOG) == -1)
                ErrorServer("listen", true);

            printf("[+] Server is waiting for incoming connections...\n");
            printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");

            user tmpCli;

            //Starting lobby's thread
            if(pthread_create(&lobby_tid, NULL, Lobby, NULL) == -1)
                ErrorServer("pthread_create()", true);
        if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sig, NULL) == -1)
            ErrorServer("changing SIGINT handler", false);

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){

            printf("Listening...\n");

            while((client_sock_ds = accept(socket_ds, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clientLength)) == -1);

            printf("[+] --------- New client connected ---------\n");

            // Receiving username
            do{

                if((res =recv(client_sock_ds, tmpCli.username, (size_t)MAX_USERNAME_DIM, 0)) == -1)
                    ErrorServer("recv() username",true);

                tmpCli.username[MAX_USERNAME_DIM-1] = '\0';

                if(debug)
                    printf("username received : %s\n", tmpCli.username);

                if(getClientByName(&Clientlist, tmpCli.username) != NULL){

                    printf("Username already taken\n");
                    strcpy(check, "there is");

                }else{

                    printf("Valid username\n");
                    strcpy(check, "there isn't");
                }

                send(client_sock_ds, check, sizeof(check), 0);

            }while(strcmp(check, "there is") == 0);

            tmpCli.client_address = client_addr;
            tmpCli.client_ds = client_sock_ds;
            tmpCli.status = true;

            insertClient(&Clientlist, tmpCli);

            // Send new user struct to thread lobby to handle connection requests
        }

        // For the moment i'm handling connections here...
        pthread_join(lobby_tid, NULL);

        printf("I'am exiting!\n");

        exit(0);

    }
```

**client.c**

```
        #include "Client_List.h"

        void Talk(char *);
        void *ThreadWorks(void * arg);
        void SIGINT_handler();

        bool debug = true;
        bool quit = false;
        int socket_ds;

        int main(int argc, char** argv){

            int res;
            struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
            char check[32];
            char buff[MAX_MSG_DIM];
            char username[MAX_USERNAME_DIM];
            char ipAddr[24];
            char choose[MAX_USERNAME_DIM]; 
            struct sigaction sig;
            sigset_t set;

            sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
            sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
            sig.sa_mask = set;
            sig.sa_handler = SIGINT_handler;

            // Opening a TCP socket using IP_V4
            if((socket_ds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
                Error("socket()", true);

            printf("[+] Client socket is created!\n");
        /*
            if(sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL) == -1)
                Error("sigprocmask()", true);
        */
            if(sigaction(SIGINT, &sig, NULL) == -1)
                Error("sigaction() sigint", true);

            if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sig, NULL) == -1)
                Error("sigaction(), sigusr1", true);

            // Setting up struct sockaddr
            memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NUMBER);    // to network byte order conversion

            if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(serv_addr.sin_addr)) <= 0)     // Address of the server to connec

        t to!
                Error("inet_pton", true);

            // binding the server address to the socket
            do{

                if((res = connect(socket_ds, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) == -1)
                    Error("connect", false);
            sleep(2);

        }while(res != 0);

        if(inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(serv_addr.sin_addr), ipAddr, 24) == NULL)
            Error("inet_ntop", true);

        printf("[+] Connected to the server with address %s\n", ipAddr);

        // Sending username
        do{

            printf("[+] Insert your username: ");
            scanf("%s", username);
            send(socket_ds, username, MAX_USERNAME_DIM, 0);

            if(recv(socket_ds, check, sizeof(check), 0) < 0)
                printf("[-] Error during receiving data!\n");

            if(strcmp(check, "there is") == 0)
                printf("This username already exists!\n");

        }while(strcmp(check, "there is") == 0);

        printf("[+] Username accept!\n");
```

**Client_List.h**

Client list is a file that cointan a linked list implementation, and has variable declarations. Here is just the variables part:

```
/* Client_List.h*/ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>     // For socket things
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>     // For IPPROTO_xxxx
#include <netinet/in.h>     // For bzero and sockaddr_in
#include <arpa/inet.h>      // For inet_ntoa and inet_aton
#include <poll.h>


#define MAX_MSG_DIM 1024
#define MAX_USERNAME_DIM 64
#define MAX_USERS 30
#define PORT_NUMBER 28000
#define fflush(stdin) {while(getchar() != '\n');}
#define CONNECTION_REQUEST(usr) strcat("I want to connect to: " #usr);
#define ERR_USERNAME_TAKEN "This username is already been taken"
#define END_USERSLIST "END"


typedef struct us{

    long client_ds;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    char username[MAX_USERNAME_DIM];
    bool status;

}user;

typedef struct clientNode{

    user client;
    int index;
    struct clientNode *next;

}clientNode;
```

I included just the connection part plus some things that i think are needed to inspect the code, hope somebody can help me

Thanks for your attention

Comment: You need to use the return value of `recv` since it may receive less (read its documentation). E.g. `tmpCli.username[res] = 0`.

Comment: As well as handle the return value of `send` because it may send less.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I am 90% sure that those calls are sending the right data amount, but i will add those checks. However, if the accept does not fail, the server should print the string right after it. So if the client connects (and i'm sure it does because it prints connected to the server) but the server is stuck somewhere, but there are no recv nor send before the print statement, so it should at least print it and then block, but it does just nothing.